# Two different partial differential equations from one equation

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $z=(x^2+a)(y^2+b)$. Obtain the partial differential equation by removing constants $a$ and $b$.

*Attempt 1:*

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=2x(y^2+b), \quad
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=2y(x^2+a)$

Then

$4xyz=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.

*Attampt 2:*

Let $z=(x^2+a)(y^2+b)$.
Then $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=2x(y^2+b),\quad \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}=2(y^2+b).$$
Also
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=2y(x^2+a),\quad
\frac {\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}=2(x^2+a)$$
Then $$4z=\frac {\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}\frac {\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}.$$

Now by first attempt we get a partial differential equation of order $2$. And by second attempt we get partial differential equation of order $4$.
My question is while obtaining partial differential equation is there any rule about how many time you should take derivative? I am not sure what difference does these two equations make.

Comment: You could have also gotten $$\frac{\partial^3 z}{\partial x^3}=0$$ which is third order, but you can see that there are many more solutions to this equation than the orignal. There is no unique equation you can get, but I think you should try to get the lowest order possible, so that you don't introduce extra solutions.